# angularJs $filter javascript syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Tried to filter a JSON file by $routeParams:id.
usually I do this:

```
var eventId = $routeParams.eventId;
$http.get('json/events.json')
 .success(function(data){
     angular.forEach(data,function(d){
         if(d.id == eventId)$scope.event = d;
     });

});
```

found some working code that doing this:

```
var eventId = $routeParams.eventId;
$http.get('json/events.json')
 .success(function(data){
    $scope.template = $filter('filter') (data, function(d){
    return d.id == eventId;
    })[0];
});
```

can you explain the syntax on the second example? especially the square brackets notation after the function call? and which approach is better ?

Thanks

Comment: in the second example should be: $scope.event.
my bad :)

Answer (score 1):

I think first approach is better for this purpose. 
`$filter` mainly used for templates.for example if you want to use filter
in `ng-repeat` directive.
in second example $filter returns an array of filtered data. you assigning the first element via `[0]` in the end. this might cause a range error if there is no data in that filtered array.

to ignore that error you might use

```
var filteredTemplates = $filter('filter') (data, function(d){
    return d.id == eventId;
    });
   $scope.template = (filteredTemplate.length && filteredTemplate[0])|| default_template;
```

and there is only a conditions to check so no need to use filter just loop through it, if you can't find the multi use, of filter you created.

**EDIT** : accessing the first element of an empty array will not throw error but returns `undefined`

Comment: Thanks. So putting a reference after a function:
function(element)(element){some code}[0];
 is legal ?

Comment: of-course its legal but not a good choice if can't ensure at list 1 element in that array,cause that will throws error. if you separate the code you will understand better.

Comment: i did an update to ignore that error if you use second one. please check

Answer (score 0):

Filters are used for formatting data displayed to the user.And its main purpose to format the data displayed in Angular template.
  $filter is a filter service of angular module.It holds reference to all the filters.

```
$filter('nameOfTheFilter')(array, expression, comparator)
```

Here you are getting default filter from filter service and passing in an array and an iterator function that will be called for each element in the array. And $filter('filter') returns an array, that satisfy the return condition in the iterator function.you are assigning the fist element of the filtered array to $scope.template.It may assign undefined if an empty array is returned by the filter

```
  $filter('filter') (data, function(d){
    return d.id == eventId;
    })[0];
```